# Maximal compact in conformal group is isometry group

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, complex-geometry, conformal-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $ M $ be a compact Kahler manifold. Then is it true that the maximal compact subgroup of the conformal group is the isometry group?

This seems true for the Riemann surface case.

If $ Conf(M) $ acts transitively on $ M $ does that imply $ Iso(M) $ acts transitively? If not does anyone have a counterexample?

Also

https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1960-66-01/S0002-9904-1960-10390-4/S0002-9904-1960-10390-4.pdf

seems to say something about when $ Conf(M)=Iso(M) $ if anyone could help explain it that would be appreciated.

EDIT: Question already answered here, see comments

[Can a conformal map be turned into an isometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681666/can-a-conformal-map-be-turned-into-an-isometry/1754948#1754948)

Comment: What examples did you try to work out in order to answer this question? Did you  try $S^2$ with some metric other than a metric of constant curvature?

Comment: If we take the standard embedding of the torus into $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ then the isometry group is just the 1 parameter group $ SO_2 $ of rotations around the $ z $ axis. But the conformal group is still (I think?)  $ SO_2 \times SO_2 $. So that disproves both of my conjectures in the question

Comment: Yes, the conformal group of a torus always contains $S^1\times S^1$ (can be a bit larger). But you can take literally any Riemannian metric of nonconstant curvature on the sphere or torus, this will accomplish the same result.

Comment: Ok so perhaps I can rephrase my question this way: If the complex automorphisms of $ M $ act transitively then can we always equip $ M $ with a metric such that the isometry group is transitive on $ M $? And furthermore in that case will the isometries of $ M $ always embed into the maximal compact subgroup of the complex automorphisms of $ M $?

Comment: Yes, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681666/can-a-conformal-map-be-turned-into-an-isometry/1754948#1754948).